# C++ overloaded function pointer ambiguity

Tags: c++, function-pointers, static-cast

I'm trying to pass an overloaded function pointer as shown below in the sample code.

```
class Sample
{
  uint32_t method(char* input1, double input2);
  uint32_t method(double input1);
}

template<class T, class... Args)
void processInput(T &&t, Args&&... a)
{
  std::packaged_task<uint32_t(Args...)> task(std::bind(t, a...));
  // other processing
}

// Caller invokes the below API
Sample* obj = new Sample();
processInput(static_cast<uint32_t(*)(double)>(&Sample::method), &*obj, 2.0f);
```

But this code doesn't compile. It keeps complaining that it can't determine which instance of overloaded function is intended. I referred several examples:

[C++ overloaded method pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364599/c-overloaded-method-pointer)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

Can somebody help in pointing out what is going wrong here?

Comment: Shoudln't `static_cast<double(*)(double)>` be `static_cast<uint32_t(Sample::*)(double)>` as it is a member function?

Comment: @pree Fix your typos (missing `;`, `)` instead of `>`). The function also does not return `double`.

Comment: That was it! I didn't really understand the implementation of static_cast in function overloading and was doing it wrong! Thanks @NathanOliver & LogicStuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you fix the typos, the main problem is that you're trying to cast a member function pointer to a function pointer.

That is, the following is illegal:

```
static_cast<uint32_t(*)(double)>(&Sample::method)
```

> ```
> error: invalid static_cast from type 
> ‘uint32_t (Sample::*)(double)  {aka unsigned int (Sample::*)(double)}’ 
> to type 
> ‘uint32_t (*)(double) {aka unsigned int (*)(double)}’
> ```

The syntax for a member function pointer is

```
ReturnT(ClassT::*)(ArgTs);
```

So your cast would have to be:

```
static_cast<uint32_t(Sample::*)(double)>(&Sample::method)
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Sample
{
  uint32_t method(char* input1, double input2) { return 0; }
  uint32_t method(double input1) { return 0; }
};

template<class T, class... Args>
void processInput(T &&t, Args&&... a)
{
  auto task = std::bind(t, a...);
  (void)task;
}

int main()
{
    Sample* obj = new Sample();
    processInput(static_cast<uint32_t(Sample::*)(double)>(&Sample::method), obj, 2.0f);

    return 0;
}
```