# Pass a function pointer of an overloaded member function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, overloading, pointer-to-member

I want to pass a function pointer of my function repaint() which is overloaded in 3 versions. I want to pass the one without any arguments:

```
void repaint()
```

I tried:

```
myObject = new Object(&myclass::repaint);
```

But the compiler says "I don't know which Version to choose". OK.

Then I tried

```
myObject = new Object(static_cast<void(*)(void)>(&repaint);
```

Then I got (sorry for the bad translation):

- "invalid operation on an expression of a bound member function"
- "myObject::myObject no overloaded function accepts 3 arguments"

How to pass it correctly?

Comment: 1. Is it possible to post the signature of `Object::Object(...)`
2. Seems like there is a typo in your `static_cast` line, missing `)` before `;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ overloaded method pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364599/c-overloaded-method-pointer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member function pointer and non-member function pointer are not the same thing. The type for member function pointer in your code is not correct, change it to

```
myObject = new Object(static_cast<void(myclass::*)()>(&myclass::repaint);
                                       ~~~~~~~~~
```

BTW: The `void` in parameter list is redundant.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! Seems now to be passed correctly, but it seems, my constructor is bad defined: "Conversion of argument 4 "void (__thiscall Status::* )(void)" in "void (__cdecl *)(void)" not possible". My constructor is this one: Object(void (*repaintFCT) (void));

Comment: @Christoph It seems the parameter type of constructor is not correct either. It should be something like `void(myclass::*sth)()`, i.e. `void(Status::*repaintFCT)()` for your real code. BTW: You might have to fix lots of things such as the type of member variable, etc.

Comment: Ok. But the contructor doesn't know the the class myclass. The inner class can't include the outer class definition outer_class.h. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Christoph The inner class should know outer class. What do you mean can't include? You might post the relevant code, or ask a new question (if it became a new one).

Comment: If you create an object of class 2 in class you include class2.h in class 1. But when you in include class1.h in class 2, as it is needed here, you get various errors (because if an include loop I think).

Comment: @Christoph I see. You don't have to include, forward declaration would be fine. Add `class myclass;` before the delaration of the class `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You dropped the class scope for some reason - use `&myclass::repaint` to get a pointer-to-member, like in your first code.
2. The type of the member function is `void (myclass::*)()`.
   All pointer-to-member types specify the class.

(The parameter list `(void)` is a C-ism. Prefer to leave it empty, unless you want to look really old.)