# Calling overloaded function using templates (unresolved overloaded function type compiler error)

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the address of an overloaded member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705854/how-to-get-the-address-of-an-overloaded-member-function)

I have a function overloaded for a set of types in a class inheritence heirarchy, e.g. Share with FutureShare and OptionShare derived.

```
virtual unsigned rank() const
{ return getValue(*this, rank_, &ShareUtils::getRank); } 

template<typename TShare , typename TMember, typename TGetMemberFunc >
TValue& getValue(const TShare& share, boost::optional<TMember>& member, TGetMemberFunc func)
{
    if(!member)
    {
        member.reset(func(share));
    }
    return *member;
}

boost::optional<unsigned> rank_;

//-------

static unsigned ShareUtils::getRank(const Share& share) { //... } 
static unsigned ShareUtils::getRank(const OptionShare& option) { //... } 
static unsigned ShareUtils::getRank(const FutureShare& future) { //... }
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
Share.h: In member function `virtual unsigned int Share::rank() const':
Share.h:25: error: no matching function for call to `Share::getValue(const Share&, boost::optional<unsigned int>&, <unresolved overloaded function type>) const'
```

How do I correctly call the overloaded function? I figured TShare would resolve the overload when calling func?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mark the overloaded functions static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails to compile because `ShareUtils::getRank` does not refer to a single function but to a *family* of functions (there are several signatures for this name).

You want to cast to function pointer to suppress the ambiguity, which means that you must know from the `rank` function which `getRank` should be called (which should not be a problem in your case) :

```
virtual unsigned rank() const
{ return getValue(*this, rank_, (unsigned (ShareUtils::*)(const Share&)) &ShareUtils::getRank); }
```

Comment: Apoligies, I forgot to mark the overloaded functions static.